Bottles does not open
I need some help with bottles in Ubuntu 24.10. I have flatpak installed and it is running fine with other programs, but not with bottles. When I try to open bottles via the flatpak software center it simply does not open and no error message displayed. If I try to open it via the terminal with flatpak run com.usebottles.bottles this error message is displayed:
11:42:01 (INFO) Launching with URI: None 
11:42:01 (INFO) [Activate] request received. 
11:42:01 (INFO) Bottles Started! 
11:42:01 (ERROR) Data file not found. Creating new one. 
11:42:01 (INFO) Performing Bottles checks… 
11:42:01 (INFO) Runners path doesn't exist, creating now. 
11:42:01 (INFO) Runtimes path doesn't exist, creating now. 
11:42:01 (INFO) WineBridge path doesn't exist, creating now. 
11:42:01 (INFO) Bottles path doesn't exist, creating now. 
11:42:01 (INFO) Dxvk path doesn't exist, creating now. 
11:42:01 (INFO) Vkd3d path doesn't exist, creating now. 
11:42:01 (INFO) Nvapi path doesn't exist, creating now. 
11:42:01 (INFO) Templates path doesn't exist, creating now. 
11:42:01 (INFO) Temp path doesn't exist, creating now. 
11:42:01 (INFO) LatencyFleX path doesn't exist, creating now. 
11:42:01 (INFO) Runners found:
     - sys-wine-9.0
 
MESA-INTEL: warning: ../src/intel/vulkan/anv_formats.c:763: FINISHME: support YUV colorspace with DRM format modifiers
MESA-INTEL: warning: ../src/intel/vulkan/anv_formats.c:794: FINISHME: support more multi-planar formats with DRM modifiers
11:42:01 (INFO) Catalog installers loaded 
11:42:01 (INFO) Catalog dependencies loaded 
Gdk-Message: 11:42:01.674: Error 71 (Protocol error) dispatching to Wayland display.

I have tried the following commands to fix this problem without success and the following results:
Results of sudo apt purge com.usebottles.bottles:
Error: Unable to locate package com.usebottles.bottles
Error: Couldn't find any package by glob 'com.usebottles.bottles'

Results of flatpak repair:
Working on the system installation at /var/lib/flatpak
[106/107] Verifying flathub:runtime/org.winehq.Wine.mono/x86_64/stable-24.08…
Checking remotes...

Results of flatpak update:
Looking for updates…

Info: runtime org.freedesktop.Platform branch 22.08 is end-of-life, with reason:
   org.freedesktop.Platform 22.08 is no longer receiving fixes and security updates. Please update to a supported runtime version.
Info: applications using this runtime:
   org.phoenicis.playonlinux

Info: runtime org.freedesktop.Platform.VAAPI.Intel branch 22.08 is end-of-life, with reason:
   org.freedesktop.Platform 22.08 is no longer receiving fixes and security updates. Please update to a supported runtime version.
Info: applications using this extension:
   org.phoenicis.playonlinux

Info: runtime org.freedesktop.Platform.GL32.default branch 22.08 is end-of-life, with reason:
   org.freedesktop.Platform 22.08 is no longer receiving fixes and security updates. Please update to a supported runtime version.
Info: applications using this extension:
   org.phoenicis.playonlinux

Info: runtime org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default branch 22.08-extra is end-of-life, with reason:
   org.freedesktop.Platform 22.08 is no longer receiving fixes and security updates. Please update to a supported runtime version.
Info: applications using this extension:
   org.phoenicis.playonlinux

Info: runtime org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default branch 22.08 is end-of-life, with reason:
   org.freedesktop.Platform 22.08 is no longer receiving fixes and security updates. Please update to a supported runtime version.
Info: applications using this extension:
   org.phoenicis.playonlinux

Info: runtime org.freedesktop.Platform.Compat.i386 branch 22.08 is end-of-life, with reason:
   org.freedesktop.Platform 22.08 is no longer receiving fixes and security updates. Please update to a supported runtime version.
Info: applications using this extension:
   org.phoenicis.playonlinux

Nothing to do.

Results of flatpak uninstall com.usebottles.bottles:
        ID                                    Branch         Op
 1. [-] com.usebottles.bottles                stable         r
 2. [-] com.usebottles.bottles.Locale         stable         r

Uninstall complete.

Results of flatpak install com.usebottles.bottles:
Looking for matches…

com.usebottles.bottles permissions:
    ipc                     network                        pulseaudio         wayland
    x11  Still t                   devices                        devel              multiarch
    per-app-dev-shm         system dbus access [1]

    [1] org.freedesktop.UDisks2

        ID                                Branch     Op     Remote      Download
 1. [✓] com.usebottles.bottles.Locale     stable     i      flathub      8.2 kB / 1.1 MB
 2. [✓] com.usebottles.bottles            stable     i      flathub     76.4 MB / 153.2 MB

Installation complete.

The same error message still appears if I try to run the program, however I have a vague guess where the problem could originate. During the initial installation one of the subprocesses timed out and was subsequently skimped by the installation program, however I have no idea if this actually is the origin of this problem or how to fix it.

install bottles and cli bottles are two references you might find useful as well as this Ubuntu Handbook reference on installing and deleting Flatpaks
